# How to Set Image height and width in j2me(java)

Tags: java-me, lcdui

i have created an image from the image url(lcdui image)

```
HttpConnection c = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(imageurl);
int len = (int)c.getLength();

if (len > 0) 
{
is = c.openDataInputStream();
byte[] data = new byte[len];
is.readFully(data);

img = Image.createImage(data, 0, len);
```

i want to set height and width to this?and i want to display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **can't set width and height** to Image. But, you **can resize** the image using the below method.

```
public Image resizeImage(Image src, int screenHeight, int screenWidth) {
        int srcWidth = src.getWidth();

        int srcHeight = src.getHeight();
        Image tmp = Image.createImage(screenWidth, srcHeight);
        Graphics g = tmp.getGraphics();
        int ratio = (srcWidth << 16) / screenWidth;
        int pos = ratio / 2;

        //Horizontal Resize        

        for (int index = 0; index < screenWidth; index++) {
            g.setClip(index, 0, 1, srcHeight);
            g.drawImage(src, index - (pos >> 16), 0);
            pos += ratio;
        }

        Image resizedImage = Image.createImage(screenWidth, screenHeight);
        g = resizedImage.getGraphics();
        ratio = (srcHeight << 16) / screenHeight;
        pos = ratio / 2;

        //Vertical resize

        for (int index = 0; index < screenHeight; index++) {
            g.setClip(0, index, screenWidth, 1);
            g.drawImage(tmp, 0, index - (pos >> 16));
            pos += ratio;
        }
        return resizedImage;

    }
```

Comment: The above code (which does not compile) may have be taken from the example on this page - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/image-resizing-137933.html - which does compile but, in my testing, does not resize the image properly as it leaves a white band at the bottom of the image.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to set the width and height because during image loading this information is loaded and set. So, if the image is 320x100, your code will create a 320x100 image.
`img.getWidth()` would return 320. `img.getHeight()` would return 100.

It is not possible to change the width and height of an `Image` object. You can just query its width and height.

Your image is ready to be presented in a `ImageItem` object ou blit in a canvas.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer didn't work for me (as it left a white band along the bottom of the image when reducing the image size - despite keeping the same aspect ratio). I found a snippet code that works from the [CodeRanch forum](http://www.coderanch.com/t/228899/JME/Mobile/resize-image).

Here is that snippet, cleaned up:

```
protected static Image resizeImage(Image image, int resizedWidth, int resizedHeight) {

    int width = image.getWidth();
    int height = image.getHeight();

    int[] in = new int[width];
    int[] out = new int[resizedWidth * resizedHeight];

    int dy, dx;
    for (int y = 0; y < resizedHeight; y++) {

        dy = y * height / resizedHeight;
        image.getRGB(in, 0, width, 0, dy, width, 1);

        for (int x = 0; x < resizedWidth; x++) {
            dx = x * width / resizedWidth;
            out[(resizedWidth * y) + x] = in[dx];
        }

    }

    return Image.createRGBImage(out, resizedWidth, resizedHeight, true);

}
```